# How can i configure imported repository path in GitLab to remove root folder prefix?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have imported an existing gitolite repository with the following command:

bundle exec rake gitlab:import:repos RAILS_ENV=production

However, it imports the repository for the Administrator user and the repository path becomes git@repository_source:root/repo_name. Since some other users use the old repository path, we don't want it to be different. In other words, we want it to be git@repository_source:repo_name. Would it be possible to configure the GitLab to remove this folder prefix for the imported repositories?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

GitLab namespaces repositories [since version 4](http://blog.gitlab.org/gitlab-4-release/), and I believe this is mandatory. You should be able to change the namespace from `root` to something else, but I don't think you can get rid of it entirely.

Users can update their remotes with [`git remote set-url`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote). Depending on the version of git you may have to run it a few times, once with `--push` and once without. Using `git remote -v` will show you when you get it right.

Assuming your remote is named `origin`:

```
$ git remote -v
origin git@repository_source:repo_name (fetch)
origin git@repository_source:repo_name (push)

$ git remote set-url origin git@repository_source:root/repo_name

$ git remote -v
origin git@repository_source:root/repo_name (fetch)
origin git@repository_source:root/repo_name (push)
```